# A Usercontrol with just a TextBlock. How do I expose the TextWrapping property to the consumer?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a minimalist `UserControl` containing a single `TextBlock` which I prototype as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockExt" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class TextBlockExt : UserControl
{
    public TextBlockExt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => textBlockExt.Text;
        set { textBlockExt.Text = value.ToUpper(); } // to be expanded later
    }
}
```

I then consume the control by

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:TextBlockExt FontSize="30" x:Name="txb" Text="Hello World" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Content="To Upper" Width="100" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And it's code behind is

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    txb.textBlockExt.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txb.Text = "one two three four five six seven eight";
}
```

I don't like the code in the `MainWindow` constructor above and need to know how to set the T`extWrapping` in the XAML.

Comment: You can do the same way it's done for `Text` property.

Comment: I’ve had this issue before. I had to extend the TextBox class one time. I chose (somewhat contrary to research) to inherit from TextBox instead of UserControl. 

You may want to think about inheriting TextBlock instead of UserControl. This would mean you can add what you need to on top of what’s already there without having to “re-expose” what’s already existing.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property TextWrapping to your TextBlockExt class. Use the same way you did for the Text property:

```
public TextWrapping TextWrapping {
    get => txtBlockExt.TextWrapping;
    set { txtBlockExt.TextWrapping = value: }
}
```